# Trying to connect to host

Tags: iot, esp8266

I'm trying to connect to Google Firebase Firestore using an esp8266 device. I want to do a post request but can't get a connection to the host:

```
const char *host = "firestore.googleapis.com";
int r=0; //retry counter
while((!httpsClient.connect(host, httpsPort)) && (r < 30)){
  delay(50);
  Serial.print(".");
  r++;
}   

 httpsClient.print(String("POST ") + "/v1beta1/projects/myproject/databases/(default)/documents/loggings" + " HTTP/1.1\r\n" +
               "Host: " + "firestore.googleapis.com" + "\r\n" +
               "Content-Type: application/json"+ "\r\n" +
               "Content-Length: 240" + "\r\n\r\n" +               
               postData+ "\r\n" +
               "Connection: close\r\n\r\n");
```

The connect() function doesn't work because the host can't be found (404). How do I need to use the connect function to get a proper connection to the firestore host?

Comment: httpsClient is an instance of WiFiClientSecure?

Comment: yes it is an instance of WiFiClientSecure

Answer (score 0):

Call httpsClient.setInsecure() before connect(). Key validation is then skipped. It's not secure but maybe that's ok for your use case. httpsPort should be 443. For me connecting to fcm.googleapis.com works if done like this:

```
WiFiClientSecure client;
client.setInsecure(); // INSECURE!
client.connect("fcm.googleapis.com", 443);
```